# Samba group access permissions

Tags: server, permissions, samba, shared-folders

I have a file/media server running Samba, Plex and Transmission. However I am having a little trouble with the access permissions of my media folder. This folder needs to grant access to the 'david', 'plex' and the 'debian-transmission user. So I made a group called 'media_users' and added them to the group and added the appropriate permission to the media folder. Now I am unable to access the shared folder from my windows machine and plex does not have a access to the files.

Does someone have an idea what I did wrong?

```
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ groupadd media_users
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo usermod -a -G media_users david
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo usermod -a -G media_users debian-transmission
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo usermod -a -G media_users plex

david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo chown -R root:media_users media
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo chmod 770 -R media
david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ ls -l
drwx------ 10 david david       10 Jul 13 00:54 david
drwxrwx---  6 root  media_users  6 Feb 26 18:12 media

david@server:/mnt/storagedata$ sudo testparm

...SNIP...

[david]
        path = /mnt/storagedata/david
        force user = david
        read only = No

[media]
        path = /mnt/storagedata/media
        read only = No
```

Answer (score 2):

Permissions are fixed by adding the group to the smb.conf file

```
valid users = @media_users
```

Answer (score 1):

Samba has a group by default to allow sharing. To add a user to that group just type `sudo gpasswd -a david sambashare`. Logout and log back in for the changes to take affect. When you map the network drive in Windows you will need to provide the credentials (linux ones) for david. Your samba configuration might need a little tweaking. Here's mine for example:

`[Chol]
    comment = Shares
    path = /home/chol
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    public = yes
    guest ok = no
    valid users = chol
    create mask = 0777
    writeable = yes`